# Как опубликовать Asp Net Core на IIS Server?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core

Читал официальную документацию и форумы, но не работает сервер.
Нужно опубликовать проект Asp Net Core на IIS сервере.
Подскажите пожалуйста пошагово, ато долбаюсь уже третий день((

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать сделать так: (VS 2017 ru )Сборка-Опубликовать.. далее выбирайте  через файловую систему, а не через сам IIS. Опубликовать все файлы в  папку сайта у вас  должно получиться  без проблем. Подробно расписано тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/20.1.php